# Aligning HTML tags properly

Tags: html, html-table

I am new to HTML alignment. I have three input fields but they are not properly aligned.

```
<form>
username:<input type="text" name="username" value="ENTER NAME HERE" /><br>
id:<input type="text" name="id" value="ENTER ID HERE" /><br>
age:<input type="text" name="age" value="ENTER AGE HERE" />
</form>
```

Please help me align using colspan or rowspan so the input fields look good one below the other.

Comment: Don't use _table_ for that, _table_ is only for textual data. Here's an [example](http://jsbin.com/asetal/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. 
It's work properly as HTML alignment vise

```
 <form>
<div style="width:300px">
<div style="float:left">username:</div><div style="float:right"><input type="text" name="username" value="ENTER NAME HERE" /></div><br>
<div style="float:left">id:</div><div style="float:right"><input type="text" name="id" value="ENTER ID HERE" /></div><br>
<div style="float:left">age:</div><div style="float:right"><input type="text" name="age" value="ENTER AGE HERE" /></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="userdata">
<div><label>Enter Name</label><input type="text" /></div>
<div><label>Enter Id</label><input type="text" /></div>
<div><label>Enter Age</label><input type="text"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use them in a table:

```
<div id="userdata">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Name</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter ID</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Age</td><td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```